# Automated Phing Deployment - Git Asking For Password

Tags: git, deployment, automation, build-automation, phing

Right now I have a Phing script that takes the files from a branch of our Git Repository, updates a server, and does a few other changes on it.

The problem is Git asks me for the password everytime -- so every night (for our nightly build), I have to do this manually, and we have 3 different systems, so I have to do it 3 times.

Is there anyway to automate this? I don't want to rely on SSH-Agent, as we may restart the server at some point, and I may forget that I then have to reactivate it, and then our nightly builds will stop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you could use an ssh agent to keep the key loaded?  That way you still can have it password protected, but don't need to enter it every time.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the script? I am trying to do the same kind of deployment with `git` and `phing`.

Comment: I believe it's proprietary -- but I believe we just removed username and password from these agents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a (new) ssh-key without password and use this for ssh-connections to your git repository. The reason, why it asks for a password is, that it *has* one ;)

For example I use a Jenkins-server, that runs under the user `jenkins`. I've created a ssh-key without password for this user and then the only thing I had to do is to publish the key to the ssh-server (`ssh-copy-id`, or (in my case) the formular in githubs account settings)

Comment: We're also using a github account and we're setting up a Jenkins server shortly (next couple of weeks), that's not unsecure at all?

Comment: As long as you can trust everybody, that have access to your server, there is nothing wrong with this